# How to restore a deleted class?

Tags: apex, metadata

I tried with below option.

```
ApexClass deletedClass = [SELECT id FROM ApexClass WHERE name = 'DeletedClass'][0];
```

My class is not found in `ApexClass`. Any other option?

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to query for deleted data that is still in the system, you need to add the `ALL ROWS` keyword.

```
undelete [SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE Name = 'DeletedClass' ALL ROWS];
```

Note this will only work if it is still in the `Recycle Bin`.

Comment: there is no such column of isDeleted on ApexClass, it means we can't restore a class

Comment: I just threw that in there as an example of how typical retrieval from the `Recycle Bin` works. It does not mean that you can't restore classes... `ALL ROWS` is the key as I stated pretty clearly.

Comment: that I understood but in the context of this question I guess you can modify the answer to avoid confusion. correct?